# Link to last incorrect review is not clickable

Tags: bug, design, review-suspension

If you make too many incorrect reviews, you will get a review suspension. As a result of this, when you visit the review page you will get a nice message, showing you your last incorrect review.

There is one minor problem: The link is not clickable.

[image]

It isn't that much of a challenge to go to this link anyway, but I don't see any reason why this link would not be clickable.

Comment: "Since this is probably fixed in under a minute" - you are making an assumption there.